# Android: How to stop a handler from a different activity ?

Tags: android, handler, runnable

In my app i create a handler in activity A than i am trying to close it from activity B. But the handler just won't stop.
Here is the user senario and the code that i use;

1. User sets a notification
2. Notification is shown and handler created
3. User tap the notification
4. Another activity opens
5. User taps the button and handler stops

This is how i try to do this ( only the handler creating and stoping parts since the rest is irrevelant ).

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
    public static Handler handler = new Handler();

    public MyAlarmService() {
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
    }
   static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendmessage();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };
    static public void stopRunnable (){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

And this is how i try to stop the handler;

```
buttonStopCountDownTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyAlarmService.stopRunnable();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Is there anyway to achive this ?

Comment: yes, use something like `startService(new Intent(...).setAction(YOUR_ACTION_INT))` then in your service you will be able get command in method `onStartCommand()`

Comment: It doesn't show it in the options when i try to put stopRunnable in place of YOUR_ACTION_INT

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive that in various ways. My favourite is:

1. extends Application class. (don't forget to register it on manifest).
2. create fields of youe MyAlarmService in it.
3. create setter and getter to this fields in the Application class.
4. call the setter in the onCreate() inside your MyAlarmService .
5. remove the static devlaration from your stopRunnable() and make it public.
6. to stop the runnable just call getApplication from anywhere in your app, cast it to your custom Application class. check if the getMyAlarmService() getter isn't null, and you could call the stopRunnable() if so.
7. don't forget to call the setter in onDestroy() of the MyAlarmService and put null on it.